# R NbClust for Python?

Tags: python, r, data-mining

Does anyone know of a Python equivalent to the R package NbClust?

I am searching for a way to determine the optimal number of clusters for many 'similar datasets' and NbClust sounds good but it is for R and I am a Python user.

Answer (score 0):

I have not found any unified package in Python like NbClust.  Check out the [Python package rpy2](https://rpy2.readthedocs.io/en/version_2.8.x/getting-started.html) for using R modules in Python.